# What is a good alternative to Bitnami packages?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, lamp, bitnami

At the company I currently work for, our servers on AWS EC2 are mostly built with WordPress packaged by Bitnami. Our PHP versions are outdated on most sites, but through some googling I've found out that to update PHP we would have to migrate the instance to one with an up-to-date Bitnami package. I would like to keep the websites on WordPress and have minimal upkeep on whatever the alternative to Bitnami is. I have little experience and so don't know if moving to Docker or something would give me the same problem later on down the line.

I tried to look up alternatives, but I'm unsure if updating parts of the pre-packaged stacks would lead to the same problem as Bitnami down the line. Is it possible to use a different stack with WordPress on an EC2 so that updating is easier in the future without completely rebuilding the website?

Comment: Moving to docker would not give you the same problem later down the line. Docker is the answer to this. And use the official WordPress docker image instead of the Bitnami image. It is easy to upgrade to newer versions of the official WordPress docker image.